# Why is there whitespace between the image and the div?

Tags: html, css

Please take a look at this link: http://bethhaim.spin-demo.com/

I can't figure out why there is a whitespace of about 3 pixels between the image and the div below it. Anyone have an idea what is causing this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your image is being displayed `display:inline` with a `line-height:18px` which is causing the spacing.

Either adjust the `line-height` to something more appropriate or set the images' display to `display:block`.

Answer (score 5):

The image tag is treated as an inline element, and it's displayed the same as if it were a long line of text.  The extra space you see is for 'descenders' of lowercase text, the part that sticks out in 'j', 'y', etc.

a `display: block` on your image will fix the gap.

More information: http://devedge-temp.mozilla.org/viewsource/2002/img-table/

Answer (score 2):

If you set your img to `display: block;` you shouldn't see the space anymore.

Answer (score 2):

add a `display: block;` to your image